# Change file permission in BlueStacks player qwerty.kl

Tags: adb, file-permissions, bluestacks

I want to edit BlueStacks `'/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl'` to add few more key map to this file, but I'm not able to edit this file due to permission issue. Any suggestions on how can I change file permission in BlueStacks. Any hacks for changing the file permission?

Res: https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/change_bluestacks_system_file_permission

Comment: You probably need to root BlueStacks. A quick search revealed [this on XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-install-and-root-the-latest-bluestacks/)

Comment: @ce4 +1 Thanks man!, your comment should be the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to root it to gain access to the protected "/system" file system.

XDA Developer's has a (probably) outdated thread how to do it [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-install-and-root-the-latest-bluestacks/).

After you suceeded, you can take the usual steps to mod it (remount /system read-write, copy your edited file over, etc.)